# Div element not aligning right after adding background-image

Tags: html, css, image, grid-layout

After adding `background-image` to my `div` element, it is not aligning in the grid correctly.

I originally tried to actually put a `<img>` tag in the `<div>` but then I changed it to `background-image`. Now it acts like a block displayed element, as it takes up the entire line and pushes the other three that are supposed to be displayed on the same line to one below it, but it doesn't have the margin on the bottom displayed, so I really have no clue what is going on.

HTML

```
<!-- Container for body content -->
    <div id="bodyContent">
        <!-- If we can find a way to make this enable us to simply put a game in a list and it automatically 
        place it accodingly, change this to that system. Maybe make just one column and have it wrap content? -->
        <div id="adBarLeft" class="adBar"> AD BAR </div>
        <div id="gameColumn"> 
            <div class="gamePreview" id="game1"> </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 2 </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 3 </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 4 </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 5 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 6 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 7 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 6 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 9 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 10 </div>
        </div>
        <div id="adBarRight" class="adBar"> AD BAR </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.gamePreview {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom:20%;
    border:3px solid orange;
    margin:1.5%; /* Figure out why this value let 4 on compared to 2.5% which didnt, but should've */
}

#game1 { /* figure out why its setting it off from the others */
  background-image: url("https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/47/cf/cf/47cfcf79-9e1d-b21f-8e10-2658b7650c15/mzl.oiljceng.png/246x0w.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

I want the image to load inside the `<div>` and have four on the same row, and then wrap around to the next line, essentially making rows with 4 `<div>`'s

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.gamePreview` class to align the inline-block to the top.

```css
.gamePreview {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  margin: 1.5%;
  vertical-align: top; /* Add this */
  /* Figure out why this value let 4 on compared to 2.5% which didnt, but should've */
}

#game1 {
  /* figure out why its setting it off from the others */
  background-image: url("https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/47/cf/cf/47cfcf79-9e1d-b21f-8e10-2658b7650c15/mzl.oiljceng.png/246x0w.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<!-- Container for body content -->
<div id="bodyContent">
  <!-- If we can find a way to make this enable us to simply put a game in a list and it automatically 
        place it accodingly, change this to that system. Maybe make just one column and have it wrap content? -->
  <div id="adBarLeft" class="adBar"> AD BAR </div>
  <div id="gameColumn">
    <div class="gamePreview" id="game1"> </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 2 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 3 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 4 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 5 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 6 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 7 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 6 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 9 </div>
    <div class="gamePreview"> 10 </div>
  </div>
  <div id="adBarRight" class="adBar"> AD BAR </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better with `display:flex` in the parent container `#gameColumn`
 , because the DIV's will accommodate the space

```css
#gameColumn{
    display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gamePreview {
    flex-basis: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border:3px solid orange;
    margin:2px; /* Figure out why this value let 4 on compared to 2.5% which didnt, but should've */
}

#game1 { /* figure out why its setting it off from the others */
  background-image: url("https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple71/v4/47/cf/cf/47cfcf79-9e1d-b21f-8e10-2658b7650c15/mzl.oiljceng.png/246x0w.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!-- Container for body content -->
    <div id="bodyContent">
        <!-- If we can find a way to make this enable us to simply put a game in a list and it automatically 
        place it accodingly, change this to that system. Maybe make just one column and have it wrap content? -->
        <div id="adBarLeft" class="adBar"> AD BAR </div>
        <div id="gameColumn"> 
            <div class="gamePreview" id="game1"> </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 2 </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 3 </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 4 </div>
            <div class="gamePreview"> 5 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 6 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 7 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 6 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 9 </div>
      <div class="gamePreview"> 10 </div>
        </div>
        <div id="adBarRight" class="adBar"> AD BAR </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of class name "adBar". It seems that when we have installed adblock in the browser, the extension seems to block the selector name 'adbar'/'adBar'. Try to switch off the adblock for the page. It will work.